# Why the result of calculating path size differs from calculating the same path, using du

Tags: files, disk-usage

I've made a script to calculate the size of current path.

```
def getFolderSize(path):
total_size = os.path.getsize(path)
for item in os.listdir(path):
    itempath = os.path.join(path, item)
    if os.path.isfile(itempath):
        total_size += os.path.getsize(itempath)
    elif os.path.isdir(itempath):
        total_size += getFolderSize(itempath)
return total_size
```

However, when I run du it shows me completely different result.

```
def du(path):
    return subprocess.check_output(['du','-sh', path]).split()[0].decode('utf-8')
```

How those two functions differs and what might cause such distinguish in results?

Comment: See [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311) (duplicate?)